# Multer fileFilter callback doesn't throw error

Tags: multer, cloudinary

I have this fileFilter code for multer. My problem is, when I call back an error, my Express app gets stuck, and eventually the page gives ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. This happens if I try to upload anything other than a jpeg.

```
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(new ExpressError("Only images are allowed", 400));
  },
});
```

the storage is a cloudinary storage which looks like so

```
const { CloudinaryStorage } = require("multer-storage-cloudinary");
const storage = new CloudinaryStorage({
  cloudinary,
  params: {
    folder: "BilbaoBarrios",
    allowedFormats: ["jpeg", "png", "jpg"],
  },
});
```

Also, strangely, if I put the storage variable after FileFilter, it will also work with pngs, but still not with any other file format, which means order is in play here.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, is Cloudinary being accessed within an in-office platform and behind a firewall (or VPN)? In case you are accessing it behind a firewall, delivering images & other Cloudinary assets sometimes requires whitelisting the Cloudinary domain (res.cloudinary.com) on your firewall.

Also, you can check out the sample I have on this link and see if it is blocked as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/upload-feature-demo-ckvgi?file=/src/CldUploaderForm.js

Comment: It isn't being accessed behind a firewall or VPN. The only problem is if I try to throw an Error in the callback of fileFilter, the application fails, but I don't get any server-side errors in the terminal, it just hangs

Comment: You could access the Cloudinary server when whitelisting the domain `res.cloudinary.com` on your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wrapped multer once and used it as middleware.

#### middleware/multer.js

```
const ErrorHandler = require("./error-handler");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

function validator(types) {
    const arr = [];

    for (let type of types) {
        switch (type) {
            case "IMAGE":
                arr.push("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
                break;
            case "PDF":
                arr.push("pdf");
                break;
            case "EXCEL":
                arr.push("excel", "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                break;
        }
    }

    regex = new RegExp(arr.join("|"), "gi");

    return { regex, extensions: arr };
}

/**
 * @param {String} form upload form ex) single|array|fields
 * @param {String|Object[]} field fieldname of upload file
 *      ex) single = 'image'
 *      ex) array = ['image', 5]
 *      ex) fields = [{name: 'image'}, {name: 'msds', maxCount: 1}]
 * @param {String[]} condition field's extension type condition [fieldname: "image", extensionTypes: ["IMAGE"]]
 */
module.exports = ({ form, field, condition }) => {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        let allowExtensions;

        const upload = multer({
            dest: "uploads/",
            fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
                const [regCondition] = condition.filter((v) => v.fieldname == file.fieldname);
                if (!regCondition) {
                    return cb("UNDEFINED_EXTENSTION_TYPE", false);
                }
                const { regex, extensions } = validator(regCondition.extensionTypes);
                allowExtensions = extensions;

                const extname = regex.test(path.extname(file.originalname));
                const mimetype = regex.test(file.mimetype);
                if (extname && mimetype) {
                    return cb(null, true);
                } else {
                    return cb("EXTENSION_TYPE_ERROR", false);
                }
            },
        });

        let uploader;
        switch (form) {
            case "single":
                uploader = upload.single(field);
                break;
            case "array":
                uploader = upload.array(field[0], field[1]);
                break;
            case "fields":
                uploader = upload.fields(field);
                break;
        }

        uploader(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                if (err == "EXTENSION_TYPE_ERROR") {
                    e = new ErrorHandler(412, 5252, `Not allow file extension. Only files with the following extensions can be uploaded. [${allowExtensions.join(", ")}]`);
                } else {
                    console.log(` >> Undefined multer error. ${err}`);
                    e = new ErrorHandler(500, 5252, "Internal Server Error");
                }
                e.handle(req, res);
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    };
};
```

#### middleware/error-handler.js

```
const query = require("mysql2/promise");
const colors = require("colors/safe");

class ErrorHandler {
    constructor(statusCode, errorCode, msg, Error) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode ?? 500;
        this.errorCode = errorCode ?? 9999;
        this.msg = msg ?? "Undefined Error";
    }

    async handle(req, res, option) {
        try {
            const [error] = await query("SELECT * FROM error WHERE id = ?", [this.errorCode]);
            if (error) {
                this.msg = error.message ? error.message : this.msg;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            this.errorCode = 5999;
            this.msg = "An unexpected error occurred during error handling";
        } finally {
            console.log(`!! Error Occur ${colors.red(this.errorCode)} - ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`);
            console.log(`Message : ${colors.green(this.msg)}`);
            console.log(`URL : ${req.method} ${colors.bold(req.originalUrl)}`);
            console.log(`UserId : ${colors.green(req.auth?.id)}`);
            console.log("Request : ");
            if (req.method === "GET" || req.method === "DELETE") {
                console.log(req.query);
            } else {
                console.log(req.body);
            }

            res.status(this.errorCode).json({msg: this.msg});
        }
    }
}

module.exports = ErrorHandler;
```

#### routes/index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const asyncify = require("express-asyncify");
const router = asyncify(express.Router());
const multer = require("@/middlewares/multer");

router.post("/single", multer({ form: "single", field: "image", condition: [{ fieldname: "image", extensionTypes: ["IMAGE"] }] }), async (req, res) => {
    const image = req.file;

    // Do it your service

    res.success(201);
});

router.post("/fields", multer({
    form: "fields",
    field: [
        { name: "images", maxCount: 10 },
        { name: "files", maxCount: 10 },
    ],
    condition: [
        { fieldname: "images", extensionTypes: ["IMAGE"] },
        { fieldname: "files", extensionTypes: ["IMAGE", "PDF"] },
    ],
}), async (req, res) => {
    const { images, files } = req?.files ?? {};

    // Do it your service

    res.success(201);
});

module.exports = router;
```